# How can I perrform the post call using java

Tags: java, html

I am using below html to call one of my server api(rest)

```
<html>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/service/uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="smallSize" value="50x50">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

how can I call this api using a java method?

Comment: You can use common-http-client.jar and you can explore there classes to send HttpRequest via Java code

Comment: You can use `Jersey` to make POST callbacks. http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Comment: I think using Apache HTTP client api would be better. in which you can create client with above parameters and execute it to target your servlet or rest api..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be following lines could help you. I am using Apache Http api.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);     
    HttpPost    post   = new HttpPost( "http://localhost:8080/service/uploadFile"));
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );
    StringBody size= new StringBody("50x50");
    entity.addPart("smallSize", size);
    entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File("D:/abc.txt") ));
    post.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    String responseFromServer = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8" );
    client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    System.out.println("response from server: "+responseFromServer);
```

where `HttpPost` and `HttpGet` class available based on your request type. For sending file, we need to use `MultipartEntity` class. if you want to send other form fields along with your `FileBody` like any metadata, you can use `StringBody`.

I hope this can help you a little. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the POST request by using a socket using the address to that form on port 80

```
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");

    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 80);

    String path = "/servlet";
    BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
    wr.write("POST " + path + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
    wr.write("Content-Length: " + data.length() + "\r\n");
    wr.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    wr.write("\r\n");

    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
```

Example taken from [HERE](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/SendingaPOSTRequestUsingaSocket.htm)

Comment: Question is about sending multipart post and not simple post.

Comment: @JunedAhsan your right , i missed that . Maybe there is a way to achieve this using sockets but i didn't try it yet.